# Java Array returning weird output

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm creating a method for a homework problem that returns the highest value in an array. I'm using a for
loop to input the numbers into the array. Here is what the input code looks like.

```
int[] array = new int [n];
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i]=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(array);}
```

When i run the program to try and see if there's anything wrong as a I go along I notice the array not returning the value I input into it. For example
putting the number **12** it returns **[I@6c80d028**. I'm pretty new to java so I don't really know what's going on with the input. Is there any thing that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do this

```
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

or

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

when you

```
System.out.println(array);
```

It prints the address and not the value hence you see a junk characters / not expected value.